# Building a recursive menu tree in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to build a recursive menu tree that outputs/builds an array, rather than markup. I've figured out the markup method but can't work out how to build this into a PHP array?

I'm using the ProcessWire API for some children checks but otherwise it's regular PHP.

```
function menuTree(Page $parent, $enter, $exit = null) {
    foreach ($parent->children() as $child) {
        call_user_func($enter, $child);
        if ($child->numChildren > 0) {
            menuTree($child, $enter, $exit);
        }
        if ($exit) {
            call_user_func($exit, $child);
        }
    }
}

menuTree($pages->get(1131), function(Page $page) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . $page->url . '">' . $page->title . '</a>';
    if ($page->numChildren > 0) {
        echo '<ul>';
    }}, function(Page $page) {
    echo '</li>';
    if ($page->numChildren > 0) {
        echo '</ul>';
    }
});
```

I'm after something like the following:

```
menu => array(
    main => array(
        1023 => array(
            id => 1023
            title => 'Menu item 1',
            children => null
        ),
        1024 => array(
            id => 1024
            title => 'Menu item 1',
            children => array(
                3000 => array(
                  id => 3000
                  title => 'Child menu item 1',
                  children => null
                ),
                3001 => array(
                  id => 3001
                  title => 'Child menu item 2',
                  children => null
                )
            )
        ),
        1024 => array(
            id => 1024
            title => 'Menu item 1',
            children => array(
                3000 => array(
                    id => 3000
                    title => 'Child menu item 1',
                    children => array(
                        4001 => array(
                          id => 4001
                          title => 'Child menu item 2',
                          children => null
                        ),
                        4002 => array(
                          id => 4002
                          title => 'Child menu item 2',
                          children => null
                        )
                    )
                ),
                3001 => array(
                  id => 3001
                  title => 'Child menu item 2',
                  children => null
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: where's your attempt to turn it into an array? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Also what's wrong with the existing Page->Children structure already present in the objects being turned into HTML? It seems that would largely do the job

Comment: @ADyson page->children() isn't recursive and I'm unsure where to place my array()s

Comment: Well, to begin with it would probably make some sense to put calls to populate arrays in place of (some of) the echo statements. Since that's what you're trying to replace. If you can't figure it out, write your logic out on paper first.